# Match is not obtained by using match_phrase_prefix in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, angular5

I have used match_phrase_prefix. It provides results if I have searched by entering some characters, but when I add some more characters to the search field, query returns zero hits.

For example: if I type `abcd` it returns match. 
But if I type `abcd e` then even if there is match, I didn't get the hit.

Following is the query I have used

here `_field`: is the filed name and

`_queryText`: is the search field value that I enter.

Can I use must or should condition or minimum should match here if yes then how?
Thanks in advance

```js
{
  body: {
    'query': {
      'match_phrase_prefix': {
        [_field]: _queryText
      },
    },
    'size': 15,
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the docs which you expect it to match?

Comment: let me know my answer solves ur issue or you have anything to ask reg my answer

Comment: I got your answer but my issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

[Match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) is the same as match_phrase, except that it allows for prefix matches on the last term in the text.

In your case, when you search for `abcd` as it the only term in the search query, it will make a prefix query and documents containing `abcd`, `abcde` , `abcdef` all will match.

But as soon as you change your search query to `abcd e`, it has a two words `abcd` and `e`. It will make a match query on `abcd` and prefix query on `e`, so documents containing `abcd` followed by `e` or `ef` or `efg` will match.

It would be better if you can provide your sample docs so that I can explain it better what should match and what shouldn't and the reason behind it.

Comment: For example if i am searching company name as Infosys. Once i type as Infosys, list of companies that include infosys in their name pops up but as soon as I type Infosys Li then only company names with Li should pop up but instead other name which do not include Li pops up.

Comment: @vikrantbute, can u provide the documents which come in search results when u search for `Infosys Li` ?